# .blur() event not fire with selector having two class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here in **[Sample DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satinder_singh1/fUKu6/)**
i want to fire event when ever class `.drow1 .subval` lost focus, might be am missing something,

**JS:**

```
$(".drow1 .sub_val").on('blur',funtion(){
alert("hello");
});
```

**Html:**

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> one</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="600" class="sub_val" />
        </td>
        <td>dummy text</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="drow1">
        <td> Two</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="50" class="sub_val" />
        </td>
        <td>drow1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="drow1">
        <td> Three</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="30" class="sub_val" />
        </td>
        <td>drow1</td>
    </tr>
     <tr class="drow2">
        <td> Four</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="30" class="sub_val" />
        </td>
        <td>drow 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Edited:
table row having class `.drow1` is created dynamically, so its not getting fire

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a typo in your code, `funtion` should be `function`:

```
$(".drow1 .sub_val").on('blur',function(){
   alert("hello");
});
```

Edit: If you are creating the elements dynamically, you should delegate the event:

```
$("table").on("blur", ".sub_val", function() {
    alert("hello");
});
```

Comment: @Satindersingh Well, actually typo is a common issue, checking the console is not a bad idea :)

Comment: It works on jsfiddle, as in my page am creating it dynamically, there it is not fire

Comment: @Satindersingh [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-element).